# How to import image conditionally

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I just upgraded my React version to 17.0.2.

Unfortunately, some of my code is not working. Image is not displayed.

This code is one of IMG tag in jSX, and what I did is set 'Src' path dynamically.
It was working without any issue on my previous React version.
Is there any solution to fix this issue?

```
<img src={require(`../${config.path}/${config.icon}`)} alt='App Icon' />
```

Comment: There isn't enough info here, it'll be to do with your build tooling not the React version upgrade. Also this is not the normal way to import images in either CRA or NextJS for example.

Answer (score 1):

In React.js latest version v17.x, we can not require the local image we have to import it.
like we use to do before

```
require(`../../${config.icon}`);
```

Now we have to you have to put all your images into public folder and then

```
<img src={`../${config.icon}`}></img>
```

this method will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there's no other way, I'll go with your opinion. :)

Comment: sure, you can explore on this